# Syntax Error: expected an indented block python

Tags: python-3.x

> Syntax Error: expected an indented block python

I'm getting the error above while trying to compile the following code.
I need help to determine the cause of the problem.

```
def clinic():
    print ("You've just entered the clinic!")
    print ("Do you take the door on the left or the right?")
    answer = raw_input("Type left or right and hit 'Enter'.").lower()
    if answer == "left" or answer == "l":
    print ("This is the Verbal Abuse Room, you heap of parrot droppings!")
    elif answer == "right" or answer == "r":
    print ("Of course this is the Argument Room, I've told you that already!")
    else:
    print ("You didn't pick left or right! Try again.")
    clinic()

clinic()
```

Comment: Please put all code in a code block using the { } symbol

Comment: None of the if or else statements are indented... How is this any different than all the other indent error question?

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in python is very important. Read this if you are not sure: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php

```
def clinic(): 
  print ("You've just entered the clinic!") 
  print ("Do you take the door on the left or the right?") 
  answer = raw_input("Type left or right and hit 'Enter'.").lower() 
  if answer == "left" or answer == "l": 
      print ("This is the Verbal Abuse Room, you heap of parrot droppings!") 
  elif answer == "right" or answer == "r": 
      print ("Of course this is the Argument Room, I've told you that already!") 
  else: 
      print ("You didn't pick left or right! Try again.")

clinic()
```