# IndentationError::expected an indented block

Tags: python-3.x

I have successfully install pattern3 for python 3.6 in my Linux system.
But after writing this code I got an error.

```
from pattern3.en import referenced  
print(referenced('university'))
print(referenced('hour'))
```

> IndentationError::expected an indented block

Comment: Both print functions are in different line

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Include the details in your question body.

Comment: This may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218230/syntax-error-expected-an-indented-block-python?rq=1

Comment: Thank you @Dragonthoughts but This stackoverflow.com/questions/44218230/ is not in my case

Comment: This is the problem of API

Comment: @Dragonthoughts have a look at this page https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-en here it uses the pattern for python2 but I have to use pattern3 for python3

Comment: The error message tells you that you need to indent your block. Have you actually tried that?

Comment: I have only 3 lines of code which is given above... I don't think there is any indentation issue

Comment: I asked if you had tried it, not whether you thought it might be. But please read the error message. It is pretty clear that it expected an indented block.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by entering to the problematic file, which should be `(C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pattern3\text\tree.py)` and fixing the problem myself:

```py
from itertools import chain  # 34
try:                         # 35
    None                     # ===> THIS IS THE LINE I ADDED! <===
except:                      # 37
    izip = zip  # Python 3
```

Obviously, this is not a suitable answer for production environments. 
Alternatively, clone the current pattern repository on your computer and install it:

```sh
git clone -b development https://github.com/clips/pattern
cd pattern
python setup.py install
```

Then you must import `pattern` instead of `pattern3`.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Python will give you an error `expected an indented block` if you skip the indentation:
Example of this:

```
if 5 > 2:
print("Five is greater than two!")
```

run it,and it will give an error

```
if 5 > 2:
  print("Five is greater than two!")
```

run it,it will not give any error.

Comment: That's fine and all, but the OP's code doesn't have any of that.

Comment: that's only a example.And I forged it to write "ex".